# Сохранение данных при смене ориентации экрана

Tags: xml, android, dom

В этом классе парсю xml:

```
public class Api {

public static final String DEPUTY_URL = "http://api.duma.gov.ru/api/da02e8ad97eccca82945f31f1f6a11be658ece85/deputies.xml?app_token=appf2bdd14a7f7aa9ec49400683486940bd8c67c3e8&current=1&position=";

private RequestQueue mQueque;
private ArrayList<Deputy> deputies = new ArrayList<Deputy>();
private OnDepDownloadListener mListener;
XMLParser parser;

public Api(Context context) {
    mQueque = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
}

public void downloadDepData() {
        String url;
        try {
            url = DEPUTY_URL + URLEncoder.encode("Депутат ГД", "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            url = "";
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        parser = new XMLParser();
                        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(response);
                        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_DEPUTY);
                        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                            NodeList nl2 = e
                                    .getElementsByTagName(KEY_FR_FRACTION);
                            Fraction fraction = null;
                            for (int k = 0; k < nl2.getLength(); k++) {
                                Element e2 = (Element) nl2.item(k);
                                fraction = new Fraction(parser.getValue(e2,
                                        KEY_FR_ID), parser.getValue(e2,
                                        KEY_FR_NAME));
                            }

                            Deputy deputy = new Deputy(parser.getValue(e,
                                    KEY_ID), parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME),
                                    parser.getValue(e, KEY_POSITION),
                                    fraction);
                            deputies.add(deputy);
                        }
                        mListener.onDownloadDepData(deputies);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("Error", error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
        mQueque.add(stringRequest);
}

public void setOnDepChangeListener(OnDepDownloadListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

}
```

Вот MainActivity:

```
   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    OnDepDownloadListener {
ListView depLv;
Api api;
DialogFragment dlg1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dlg1 = new Dialog1();
    dlg1.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dlg1");
    dlg1.setCancelable(false);
    depLv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    api = new Api(this);
    api.setOnDepChangeListener(this);
    api.downloadDepData();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDownloadDepData(ArrayList<Deputy> deputies) {
    DeputyArrayAdapter adapter = new DeputyArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deputies);
    depLv.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    dlg1.dismiss();
}
```

}

Хочу чтобы после поворота экрана заново не скачивался xml и не парсился, а использовался уже готовый `ArrayList`. Как мне сохранить его и добавить в `ArrayAdapter`?(сейчас у меня в `onCreate` создается новый экземпляр Api и заново записывается массив) Как правильно это реализуется? И вообще правильно я использую библиотеку Volley?

Answer (score 2):

Сохраняйте в `onSaveInstanceState()`, восстанавливайте сохранённые ранее значения в `onCreate()` или в `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Comment: только вот я не совсем понимаю, как мне получить доступ к массиву deputies, который используется в onDownloadDepData, в onSaveInstanceState()?

Comment: Сохраняем: `outState.putSerializable("data", deputies);`

Восстанавливаем: `deputies = (ArrayList<Deputy>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("data");`